# Why does my system takes so long to recognize that I'm typing in the keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, configuration

Hello fellow Linux users, I would like to ask you for help. I am running on 12.04 and Windows 7 (dual boot).

I have some Trust keyboard, and it is working fine in Windows7, but when I log into Ubuntu, I must press key harder and I must hold 'em a while.
I even tried set something up in keyboard setting, but that is not helping me.

So, what should I do?

Comment: If you have `usb` keyboard then just try to plugin in some other `usb port`.. See what happens..